# Random sample of big big numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, random, sampling

Consider the following piece of code:

```
m = 2;
n = 6;
samplesize = 1000;
totalsize = 2^(n^m);
numbersample = 2 RandomSample[Range[totalsize/2], samplesize];
```

With this I want to get a `RandomSample` of `samplesize` even numbers between `1` and `totalsize`. I am getting the error `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`, due to the size of the list `Range[totalsize/2]` (although the size of the sample I need is small). How can I modify my code to run within my memory and get the same (maybe) result?

Comment: `RandomInteger[{1, 2^(6^2 )}, 1000]`?

Comment: subtle difference, `RandomSample` ensures no repeats. `RandomInteger` could repeat with extremely small probability with these numbers.

Comment: @Kuba yeah.....

Comment: @george2079 That's right, with this size of set I shouldn't worry about repetitions...

Comment: You can use `Span` to avoid the blowup from `Range`: `RandomSample[1 ;; totalsize/2, samplesize]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau that should be an (the) answer. Don't know why they buried that down under examples in the docs.

Comment: `RandomSample` does accept a `Span` argument, too. Like, `RandomSample[1 ;; 1000, 100]`. It does have an unnecessary limitation - or a bug, though: spans with upper limit of 2^63 or higher appear to fail. I have reported this issue as CASE:4032856.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ach. I should have read the comments. Nonetheless, there's an unnecessary limitation on this functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Span` to avoid the blowup from `Range`:

```
m = 2;
n = 6;
samplesize = 10;
totalsize = 2^(n^m);
numbersample = 2 RandomSample[1 ;; totalsize/2, samplesize]

(* Out[145]= {27031562174, 37752159722, 45591082014, 64125204586, \
66565096356, 29240167748, 42466822774, 11081960620, 37360181228, \
31719722938} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could experiment a bit with the following function

```
randomSampleOfRange = 
 Compile[{{totalsize, _Integer}, {samplesize, _Integer}},
  Block[{rand, a},
   rand = Table[RandomInteger[{1, (totalsize - i)}], {i, 0, samplesize - 1}];
   Do[
    a = rand[[i]];
    Do[If[rand[[j]] <= a, a++];, {j, 1, i - 1}];
    rand[[i]] = a;
    rand[[1 ;; i]] = Sort[rand[[1 ;; i]]];
    ,
    {i, 2, Length[rand]}];
   rand
   ]
  ]
```

Use it like this

```
m = 2;
n = 6;
samplesize = 1000;
totalsize = 2^(n^m);
numbersample = 2 randomSampleOfRange[Quotient[totalsize, 2], samplesize];
```

I am not entirely sure that the function `randomSampleOfRange` works as intended, so please tell me if you experience any oddities.

Comment: That worked absolutely well (using `numbersample = 2 randomSampleOfRange[totalsize/2, 1000]`), also with greater values. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. You're welcome!